# bootstrap: Insert <hr/> at responsive

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I am designing a website using the responsive Bootstrap framework.

I have 3 content areas next each other (horizontally). If I have a small display, these 2 contents are under each other (typical responsive design).

Now I want to add a `<hr/>` after each content block that is under each other.

```
<div class="row-fluid content">
  <div class="span4">test1</div>
  <div class="span4">test2</div>
  <div class="span4">test3</div>
</div>
```

This is the whole code for a big display.

On some displays there are 2 blocks horizontal and 1 block under the 2 blocks.
Then I want to insert a `<hr/>` between the 2 lines.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking.

Comment: You'd have to use something like javasript/jquery to insert the `<hr/>` tag in-between your content divs when the @media size is reached in your css.

Comment: Unless you have intentionally customised the CSS, the above HTML shouldn't result in 2 span4 blocks side by side with the 3rd underneath, no matter what the viewport. Do you have a URL you can post?

Answer (score 5):

Bootstrap provides classes to manage the visibility of any element by device, based on media queries. You have to place `<hr/>` elements wich are only visible in specific viewports:

```
<div class="row-fluid content">
    <div class="span4">test1</div>
    <hr class="visible-phone"/>
    <div class="span4">test2</div>
    <hr class="visible-phone"/>
    <div class="span4">test3</div>
</div>
```

Check the documentation for more [Responsive utility classes](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#responsive).